# Safari/Babel/Webpack Const declarations are not supported in strict mode

Tags: safari, webpack, babeljs

Safari is failing to load my React app with this line:

```
Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
```

When I look at the line that's failing I'm seeing:

```
const Crypto = __webpack_require__(624)
```

This isn't something in my app so it must be injected by Webpack or another dependency.

Shouldn't Babel replace `const` with `var`?

**Babel Dependencies**

```
"babel": "~6.1.0",
"babel-core": "~6.2.0",
"babel-loader": "~6.2.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "~6.1.0",
"babel-polyfill": "~6.2.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "~6.1.0",
"babel-preset-react": "~6.1.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "~6.1.0",
"babel-runtime": "~6.2.0"
```

**Babel Loader Config**

```
{
  test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  query: {
    cacheDirectory: true,
    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
    presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
  }
}
```

**NOTE** My app does work in Chrome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've excluded "node_modules" in babel-loader settings, so it doesn't process your external dependencies. This package you depend on probably is not tested for in-browser usage.

<s>And, btw, babel won't replace your consts anyway unless you use "transform-es2015-block-scoping" plugin.</s>

http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-block-scoping/

It's not included in "es2015" preset. There you have only "check-es2015-constants" plugin which just checks and validates const declarations.

The plugin which transforms consts into vars is called "transform-es2015-block-scoping" and it's included in "es2015" preset.

Comment: According to http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/ the transform-es2015-block-scoping plugin is included in the es2015 preset.

Comment: Can anyone update this for a 2018 solution?  I think this is a similar situation to [my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387447/bundle-js1-syntaxerror-unexpected-keyword-const-const-declarations-are-not) but it doesn't seem up to date with the reference to `es2015` preset?

Comment: Oh my god. I've been trying to get babel to compile to es5 since yesterday. I finally fixed the issue thanks to your answer about removing the exclude node_modules setting. 

Comment: @Neil same here. Must have picked up the snippet at the same place as you have.