# Const declarations are not supported in strict mode on certain browsers

Tags: material-ui, strict

When I run my app in the iOS iPhone 6 simulator (or my physical iPad2) I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.
=> reactBoilerplateDeps.dll.js:4088
```

Which leads to the `is-in-browser` module included by `jss`:

```
export const isBrowser = typeof window === "object"
    && typeof document === 'object'
    && document.nodeType === 9;

export default isBrowser;
```

I'm using these packages:

- [material-ui@v1.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.1)
- [react-boilerplate@v3.4.0](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/tree/v3.4.0)

How do I correct this? Maybe the `transform-es2015-block-scoping` plugin as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878586/safari-babel-webpack-const-declarations-are-not-supported-in-strict-mode) ?

The app works fine on my **physical** iPhone 6 and desktop browser(s) but not on my iPad2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const) this is fixed in [iOS] Safari 10, so you might be able to get away with telling people who run into this issue that their browser isn't supported, and they should update it, but that's really not a good solution.

Also, note that when [twig.js](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js) hit [this issue](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/issues/470), their fix was to [declare with the `var` keyword instead of `const`](https://github.com/twigjs/twig.js/commit/89f5f18b3f2c33df2ac88dcbf696d29659f08f51), so perhaps you should [submit a bug report](https://github.com/tuxsudo/is-in-browser/issues) to [`is-in-browser`](https://github.com/tuxsudo/is-in-browser) about this.

It would also be a good idea to try to see if using the `var` keyword instead of `const` works for you, by editing the file where you found `export const isBrowser ...` to replace `const` with `var`. This information will help if you decide to submit a bug report, and if it does work, you could create a fork of their repository with your fix, and submit a pull-request.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `is-in-browser` was not built with correct babel settings. You can try going to `node_modules/is-in-browser` and run `npm run build` to rebuild it.