# bundle.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode

Tags: webpack

I have a site that works fine on my iPad and desktop, but not on other devices I am testing at browserstack.com  (eg Safari on iPhone 6S) and my iPhone 4.

Visually, it just looks like the `CSS` and `JS` is just not loading.

The dev tools console error at browserstack is:

> bundle.js:1 SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const
>   declarations are not supported in strict mode.

My `webpack.config.json` has this rule:

```
rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                presets: ["env", "stage-0"]
            }
        }
    },
```

And `.babelrc` is:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "stage-0"
    ]
}
```

And `package.json` has:

```
"devDependencies":
{
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.5",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "less": "^3.0.4",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "uikit": "^3.0.0-rc.16",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution:

> You've excluded "node_modules" in babel-loader settings, so it doesn't
>   process your external dependencies. This package you depend on
>   probably is not tested for in-browser usage.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34039372

Result:

I commented out the `exclude: /(node_modules)/,` line in `webpack.config.json` and the site *seems* to be working (i'm still testing all devices/browsers).  I'm a bit concerned with this solution though as there must have been a reason why i was excluding `node_modules` in the first place, but i can't remember why :(.