# Transpiling, bundling, and minifying JS without Gulp, Webpack ect - node only

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, transpiler

While I'm not opposed to using Webpack to build my JS (it's great) I just *want to know* how to do it myself.

I've used a gulp script for this in the past before recently moving to Webpack but it's frustrating how many small things I need to consider.

First I need to use browserify, and transform my JS by running the files through babelify with the es2015 preset, and then bundle it.  Apparently browserify's bundle method returns a streamable object which needs to be converted back into some other type of stream that gulp likes, which is then "buffered" so I can later minify.  The streaming conversation always tripped me up.

I was thinking something like this might work:

My Task:

```
const code = babel.transformFileSync(
    filename,
    {
        presets: ['babel-preset-env'],
        ignore: ['node_modules/'],
        sourceMaps: true
    }
);
var result = uglifyjs.minify(code.code);
```

My script

```
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
myArr = myArr.filter( e => e % 2 ==0 );
console.log(myArr);
```

But it chokes. Seems that babel does not like the use of "const" in my script

```
node_modules/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/lib/index.js:35
            throw violation.buildCodeFrameError(messages.get("readOnly", name));
```

So thats one problem, then I need to figure out how to bundle up my scripts regardless of whether or not I am using require('./custom-module.js') or import * from 'another-custom-module.js'

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a variable with const you may only assign to it on declaration.

The line

```
myArr = myArr.filter( e => e % 2 ==0 );
```

is illegal if myArr is const.

About the second problem: Normally babeljs should translate any `import` to `require`. Bundling these is now the tricky part and the reason why stuff like webpack exists. You could look into https://github.com/rollup/rollup which focuses on bundling.

Also you have to mindful about the order of operations. If you bundle first you can simply transpile the whole bundle with es6 afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/) and it didn't mention anything about native transpiling features. Maybe thats the reason about why babel and webpack build npm modules in order to add those features to NodeJS.

I think that maybe you aren't loading this piece of code:

```
node_modules/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/
```

because you are ignoring everything that is in the `/node_modules` folder.

I think that if *const* isn't supported in the version of babel that you are running, you could use webpack and search for a proper configuration, [I have read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878586/safari-babel-webpack-const-declarations-are-not-supported-in-strict-mode) that there are modules that convert *const* in to *var* declarations, since 2015 until now.

Here is a cool tutorial for webpack ---> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpGLUVbqoYQ

Hope it was helpful :)